# ActiveRecord not retrieving all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models, Car and Person. Each person can have many cars. I have loaded some data through from `seed.rb` but when I try `Car.find_by(owner_id: 1)` in the console, I see just one car. When I am expecting 2 cars because I assigned 2 cars to one particular Person. Why am I just seeing one car?

car.rb (model)

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "Person", foreign_key: "owner_id"
  has_many :place_rents
  validates :owner, presence: true
  validates :registration_number, presence: true
  validates :model, presence: true
end
```

person.rb

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars, foreign_key: "owner_id"
  has_many :parkings, foreign_key: "owner_id"
  validates :first_name, presence: true
end
```

seed.rb

```
people = Person.create([{first_name: "Emmanuel", last_name: "Hayford"}, {first_name: "Steve", last_name: "Jobs"}, 
  {first_name: "James", last_name: "Bond"}, {first_name: "Michael", last_name: "Jordan"}])

addresses = Address.create([{street: "Limanowskiego", city: "Kraków", zip_code: "98-734"}, {street: "Zeromskiego", 
  city: "Wrocław", zip_code: "45-622"}, {street: "Chopin", city: "Gdańsk", zip_code: "98-734"}, 
  {street: "Putin", city: "Opole", zip_code: "90-938"}])

cars = Car.create([{owner: Person.first, model: "BMW", registration_number: "UJ8483"}, {owner: Person.second, model: "Lambo", registration_number: "JH4857"}, 
  {owner: Person.second, model: "Jaguar", registration_number: "DW3455"}, { owner: Person.second, model: "Ferrari", registration_number: "KP8734"}, 
  {owner: Person.first,model: "Bugatti Veyron", registration_number: "ZK9837"}])

parkings = Parking.create([{kind: "indoor", hour_price: 45.50, day_price: 200, places: 5, owner: Person.first, address_id: Address.first}, 
  {kind: "outdoor", hour_price: 20.50, day_price: 150.00, places: 10, owner: Person.second, address_id: Address.second}, 
  {kind: "street", hour_price: 270.50, day_price: 89.45, places: 7, owner: Person.second, address_id: Address.second}, 
  {kind: "private", hour_price: 40.50, day_price: 30.45, places: 2, owner: Person.find(2), address_id: Address.find(2)},])

place_rents = PlaceRent.create([{parking: Parking.first, car: Car.first, start_date: Time.now, end_date: Time.now + 3.days, price: 30}])

2.1.4 :023 > Car.all
  Car Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Car id: 1, registration_number: "UJ8483", model: "BMW", owner_id: 1, created_at: "2014-11-10 00:10:26", updated_at: "2014-11-10 00:10:26">, #<Car id: 2, registration_number: "JH4857", model: "Lambo", owner_id: 2, created_at: "2014-11-10 00:10:26", updated_at: "2014-11-10 00:10:26">, #<Car id: 3, registration_number: "DW3455", model: "Jaguar", owner_id: 2, created_at: "2014-11-10 00:10:26", updated_at: "2014-11-10 00:10:26">, #<Car id: 4, registration_number: "KP8734", model: "Ferrari", owner_id: 2, created_at: "2014-11-10 00:10:26", updated_at: "2014-11-10 00:10:26">, #<Car id: 5, registration_number: "ZK9837", model: "Bugatti Veyron", owner_id: 1, created_at: "2014-11-10 00:10:26", updated_at: "2014-11-10 00:10:26">]> 
2.1.4 :024 > Car.find_by(owner_id: 1)
  Car Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "cars".* FROM "cars"  WHERE "cars"."owner_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 => #<Car id: 1, registration_number: "UJ8483", model: "BMW", owner_id: 1, created_at: "2014-11-10 00:10:26", updated_at: "2014-11-10 00:10:26"> 
2.1.4 :025 >
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your seed.rb?

Comment: There is no `find_by` in Rails3's ActiveRecord so I switched your tags to specify Rails4 (which does have `find_by`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstand how [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) works:

> **find_by(*args)**
>
> Finds the first record matching the specified conditions.

`find_by` only gets one record from the database, hence the `LIMIT 1` in the SQL it generates. If you want to find several things, then use `where`:

```
Car.where(owner_id: 1)
```

or, since you have the associations set up, use `Person#cars`:

```
person = Person.find(1)
cars   = person.cars
```

Answer (score 1):

`Car.find_by_owner_id(1)` is the same as `Car.where(owner_id: 1).first` so basically it returns one record rather than an array of record. `Car.where(owner_id: 1)` will get you your two records.